# Getting error while deleting the key value from array of objects

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, go, bson, mgo

I am getting the following error while deleting from key from array of JSON objects using Go.
Error:

```
    repository/orderRepository.go:394:11: first argument to delete must be map; have interface {}
    repository/orderRepository.go:395:11: first argument to delete must be map; have interface {}
    repository/orderRepository.go:396:11: first argument to delete must be map; have interface {}
    repository/orderRepository.go:397:11: first argument to delete must be map; have interface {}
    repository/orderRepository.go:398:11: first argument to delete must be map; have interface {}
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
    func SyncOrders() map[string]interface{} {
        logger.Log.Println("OrderRepository SyncOrders Begin")
        resourceManager := resources.ResourceManager{}
        session, error := driver.Connect()
        db := session.DB(config.Configuration.Database)
        var resp map[string]interface{}

        if error != nil {
            resp := utils.Message(resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.ERROR), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.DB_SERVER_NOT_REACHABLE_CODE), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.DB_SERVER_NOT_REACHABLE_DESC))
            return resp
        } else {
            var result []interface{}
            //filter := bson.M{"Customer.CustomerID": id, "PaymentDetails.PaymentStatus": "Payment Received"}
            //fmt.Println(filter)
            err := db.C(ORDERCOLLECTION).Find(nil).All(&result)
            if err == nil {
                resp = utils.Message(resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.SUCCESS), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.PRODUCT_GETBYID_CODE), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.PRODUCT_GETBYID_DESC))
                for i := 1; i < len(result); i++ {

                    delete(result[i],"_id");
                    delete(result[i],"CreatedAt");
                    delete(result[i],"CreatedBy");
                    delete(result[i],"UpdatedAt");
                    delete(result[i],"UpdatedBy");
                }
                resp["data"] = result
            } else {
                //fmt.Println(err)
                resp = utils.Message(resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.ERROR), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.PRODUCT_GETBYID_NOTFOUND_CODE), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.PRODUCT_GETBYID_NOTFOUND_DESC))
            }
            defer session.Close()
            return resp
        }
    }
```

Here I am fetching some record from MongoDB and delete some key value from each record but when I am running the server I am getting these errors. As I am beginner to Go. Can anybody help me to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all: the first argument to the builtin [`delete()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#delete) must be a value of static type map.

Your `result` variable is of type `[]interface{}`, so indexing it like `result[i]` will result in a value of type `interface{}`.

If it holds a map, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain the map value from it. Since you use the `mgo` driver, it is of type [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#M) (which is a `map[string]interface{}`), so you may do it like this:

```
delete(result[i].(bson.M), "_id")
```

But it would be better if you would declare `result` to be a slice of maps in the first place:

```
var result []bson.M
```

So then no type assertion will be needed, and the following will be valid code:

```
delete(result[i], "_id")
```

Also note that if you want to remove these properties from the results, it would be best if you would tell MongoDB you don't need these fields and so the server wouldn't even send these (saving network traffic) and then you wouldn't have to remove them (saving time and memory).

Use projection to tell you don't need these fields. In `mgo` you can set a projection using the [`Query.Select()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Query.Select) method.

For example:

```
err := db.C(ORDERCOLLECTION).Find(nil).Select(bson.M{
    "_id":       0,
    "CreatedAt": 0,
    "CreatedBy": 0,
    "UpdatedAt": 0,
    "UpdatedBy": 0,
}).All(&result)
```

The above query will result in documents where the listed fields will not be present, so you don't have to manually remove them using `delete()`.

Comment: Yes i used like `delete(result[i].(bson.M), "_id")` and error gone.

Comment: @user_agent But rather declare `result` to be `[]bson.M`, so you don't have to use type assertion.

Comment: Is there any other way rather than for loop where I can delete same keys from each record of document as loops takes too many time.

Comment: @user_agent Yes, use a projection to tell the server you don't need these fields, so you won't have to remove them at all. See edited answer how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete key from variable of type `interface{}`.
@icza gives a good solution.

You can use `.Select()` to select which fields should be retrieved for the results.
Then you don't need to delete those fields from every object.

For example, the following query would only retrieve the name and age field:

```
err := db.C(ORDERCOLLECTION).Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"name": 1, "age": 1}).All(&result)
```